# Include a TIMESTAMP = NOW() column in a PostgreSQL View

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm selecting columns from 3 tables into a View.

I would like a column populated with the date the View is run for each record in the View.

.

Is this possible?

Is there a better way to document the View's date?

Comment: All selections in a statement run at the same time. (Views don't affect that, they just rewrite the query)

Comment: Can you rephase? I want to know the timestamp of when the selects inside the View query was run.

Comment: The selects inside the view run all at the same time - the time when you select something from the view.

Comment: Just include it in the view: `create view ... as select ..., current_timestamp as run_at from ...`